# Swagger doesn't include import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable into generated class

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I want to use swagger openapi-generator with Ktor, but when I had  sent request to Ktor controller I got this error :

Serializer for class 'SomeRequest' is not found.

How to fix it ?

Comment: Could you please describe how exactly did you generate server stubs and what OpenAPI document did you use?